# How do I turn a Windows feature on/off from the command line in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

In Windows 10 and from "Programs and Features", you can turn Windows features on or off and then initiate a download and installation. I wish to turn ".NET Framework 3.5" ON and have it downloaded and installed, but I need to do it via e.g. a PowerShell script or via a command. I need to use the command line.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Run a command prompt **as an administrator** and use:

```
dism /online /Get-Features
```

This will display the feature names since they don't always match up with what you're seeing in that visual feature list. It will also show which are currently enabled/disabled. Once you find the feature that you'd like to enable (**NetFx3** in this case), run this:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

And as Richard stated, you can then disable a feature by simply switching "Enable" to "Disable" ex.

```
dism /online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```

**Note: Sometimes a restart is required to see changes with windows features.**

Answer (score 22):

To enable and disable features on a client machine of Windows using PowerShell, the cmdlet you have to use is:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature
```

For example, with Windows 10 and NetFX 3, I would check if the feature is enabled with

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.featurename -Like "*netfx3*"}
```

If not enabled, run this to enable it:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName "NetFx3" -Source "SourcePath"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would go about kicking off a download, but you can get the files from the `Windows 10` install CD/ISO. Copy the folder called `'D:\sources\sxs'` and store these file somewhere.

Once you have the files you can install them with the following command, run it with administrative rights. Make sure you change the `/Source:` parameter to the location you copied 'sxs' folder to.

```
DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

If you wish to unstill the feature by command line you can use the following comamnd.

```
DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:NetFx3
```